# AttributeError 'Client' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, model

I have a problem very probably silly but that I can not solve, an Attribute error after the execution of a function of views

In degug mode of my Django application I get :

```
AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'Client' object has no attribute 'get' 
(...)
Error during template rendering
In template (...)Comptabo/templates/base.html, error at line 0
```

When I click on the name of a customer in my index page. I have already tried a lot of things and looked at the corresponding topics as well as the doc, I do not understand where the error comes from. This is not a problem related to the template or the urls file .. If anyone has an idea

My client function in views.py :

```
def client(request, id = 0):
    if id:  
        client = Client.objects.get(id = id)
        form = ClientForm(client)
        factures = Facture.objects.filter(client = client)
        devis = Devis.objects.filter(client = client)
        form_fact = FactureForm()
        form_dev = DevisForm()
        return render(request,'client.html',{'client' : client
          , 'form' : form, 'factures': factures, 'devis': devis
          , 'formf': form_fact,'formd': form_dev})
    else:
        return redirect('/index')
```

My class Client in models.py :

```
class Client(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    adresse_voie = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    adresse_code = models.IntegerField()
    adresse_ville = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    adresse_pays = models.CharField(max_length = 30, default = "France")
    tel = models.CharField(max_length = 12)
    fax = models.CharField(max_length = 12, blank = True)
    mail = models.EmailField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom
```

The worst thing is that the function `Client.objects.get(id = id)` works because in local variables my client variable contains the requested object:

```
client = Client: ICE
devis = QuerySet []
factures = QuerySet []
form = ClientForm bound=True, valid=True, fields=(nom;adresse_voie;
       adresse_code;adresse_ville;adresse_pays;tel;fax;mail)
form_dev = DevisForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(prestations;total_HT;date)
form_fact = FactureForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(prestations;total_HT;paye;date)
id = 1
request = WSGIRequest: GET '/client/1/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have posted the full traceback, so we could see where the error is coming from. But this line is obviously wrong:

```
form = ClientForm(client)
```

The first positional argument to a form is the post data.You probably meant

```
form = ClientForm(instance=client)
```

Comment: Thanks you Daniel, it works... I've a project functional with python yet, but i've never saw this error, now i know how fix it and how fill a form correctly. Thank you again!! you saved my day!

Comment: But i don't undestand why the indicate error was on the get attribute of Client object

Comment: Because you've passed that object in place of the data dictionary; so where the form would normally do `request.POST.get('fieldname')`, it's now effectively trying to do `client.get('fieldname')`, hence the error.